# Updating a collection and returning it

Tags: laravel

I want to update a collection before looping through it.
Is there a way to set the sent value of the emails collection to true and return the collection before actually looping through it.

```
$emails = Email::where('sent', false);

$emails->update(array("sent" => true));

foreach ($emails as $email) {
 //send email
}
```

I want to be able to call ->get() somewhere but I cant do it on the update or the initial query

Comment: `$emails = Email::where('sent', false);` what is the current value of your test record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to call `get` on the `Email::where('sent', false)` that is an `Illuminate\Eloquent\Builder` instance.

You can use something like this:

```
tap(Email::where('sent', false)->get(), function ($emails){
    Email::whereIn('id', $emails->pluck('id')->all())->update(['sent' => true]);
})->each(function($email){
    // Send email
});
```

The `tap` function accepts two arguments, first one is a value that you want to run the second argument(which is a callback) on it, then the `tap` function returns you that first passed value and here you can easily loop through.

See [Here for tap](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-tap)

Comment: Thanks! I've never used tap before, pretty cool! I had ->get() on my query initially but i couldn't call update on it afterwards.